# Clone object with input text Angular

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, duplicates, clone

I have some fields (select and input text). The user can add new rows clicking the button 'add'. But how can i do if i want to clone the filled array, with the input?

[plnkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/z2nXgXyGi6LhSHth8ZNi?p=preview)

I mean: i select the 3° , then i write '55' in the first input type and '9' in the second one. If the user press 'add', how can i duplicate the field with the number that i wrote?

```
<button data-ng-click="cloneItem()" class="btn inline">
 Add
</button>
```

Comment: As long as the item you are cloning is all one Object, you could use [angular.copy()](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.copy).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to have the add button inside the ng-repeat and then pass the entered food object to the cloneItem function. Then you can just clone that item in that function. Using [angular copy](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.copy) function to make a copy of the food object.

Code:

Changed Controller scope function:

```
$scope.cloneItem = function (food) {
   var itemToClone = angular.copy(food);
   $scope.foods.push(itemToClone);
}
```

Changed HTML (ng-repeat loop):

```
<div ng-controller="ProductController">

      <div data-ng-repeat="food in foods track by $index">
        <div class="form-group title-field">
          <select  ng-model="food.selectproduct" >
            <option value="1">0101003 - Min. Diet pesce 2 Scd</option>
            <option value="2">0101004 - Min. Maint pesce 4 Scm</option>
            <option value="3">0101115 - Min. Diet pesce 1.5 Scd</option>
          </select>
          <input type="hidden">
          <button data-ng-click="removeItem($index)" class="btn delete-field-{{$index}}">
            Delete
          </button>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            <label> QUANTITY 1 </label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" data-ng-model="food.Quantity1" id="barcodeValue1" >
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            <label> QUANTITY 2 </label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" data-ng-model="food.Quantity2" id="barcodeValue2">
        </div>

        <div class="ean">
          <h2> CODE: </h2>
          <barcode food="food"></barcode>
        </div>
        {{food | json}}
        <button data-ng-click="cloneItem(food)" class="btn inline">
        Add
      </button>
      </div>
```

[Working Plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/uqss62bV9G0Bkb0cNUln?p=preview)

Comment: You are welcome @panagulis72. If you like the answer and it solves the purpose please have it as accepted.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you want to copy the values of the previous block when add button is clicked, you can do this:

```
$scope.cloneItem = function() {
  var food = $scope.foods[$scope.foods.length - 1];
  var itemToClone = {
    "selectproduct": food.selectproduct,
    "Quantity1": food.Quantity1,
    "Quantity2": food.Quantity2
  };
  $scope.foods.push(itemToClone);
}
```